# questions with fitting a dose response curve using drc package in r

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I am trying to use the `drm` function in `drc` package to fit a 4 PL or 3PL curve for an assay response. Please see the listed data below. When I do the curve fitting, it returns the following error message. Anyone who familiar with this have any input on what went wrong?

```
> dat
      values   log_dose
1   -68.1125  3.9120230
2   -73.8955  3.9120230
3   -75.1235  3.9120230
4   -47.3205  3.2188758
5   -52.9835  3.2188758
6   -58.0075  3.2188758
7     8.2515  2.5257286
8   -24.5925  2.5257286
9   -18.1425  2.5257286
10   75.3375  1.8325815
11   89.3755  1.8325815
12  115.9685  1.8325815
13  345.7675  1.1394343
14  470.8125  1.1394343
15  514.8985  1.1394343
16 1003.2235  0.4462871
17 1033.0345  0.4462871
18  866.1365  0.4462871
19 1383.6525 -0.2468601
20 1431.3245 -0.2468601
21 1459.8025 -0.2468601
22 1852.5795 -0.9400073
23 1917.8015 -0.9400073
24 1858.0875 -0.9400073
25 1995.1185 -1.6331544
26 2033.9455 -1.6331544
27 1991.0405 -1.6331544
28 2064.5855 -2.3263016
29 2043.5195 -2.3263016
30 2089.8525 -2.3263016
31 2147.8445 -3.0194488
32 2047.7905 -3.0194488
33 2002.5375 -3.0194488
34 2075.2665 -3.7125960
35 2068.3545 -3.7125960
36 2055.9605 -3.7125960

> mod1 <- drm(values~log_dose, fct=LL.4(), data=dat)
Error in optim(startVec, opfct, hessian = TRUE, method = optMethod, control = list(maxit = maxIt,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
Error in drmOpt(opfct, opdfct1, startVecSc, optMethod, constrained, warnVal,  : 
  Convergence failed
```

> 

Comment: I am not familiar with this kind of analysis but I note that 8 out of 36 of `values` are negative. Is that consistent with what you are trying?

Answer (score 2):

Use non-log values for your dose. the drm() function will do the conversion for you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85441)

Comment: The answer is to use non-log values for the dose variable in the model.  I asked the poster to let us know what type of serial dilution this which would help to actual post the correct input data such that the drm() function will execute successfully.

Comment: Thanks civelldr. You are right. The package assumes log logistics model. So independent values for the model must be the original concentration/dilution values.